# jquery accessing all elements who have id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all elements from a div who have `id attribute`, means i want to do something like:

```
$("div").find("*[id]").each(function() { alert(this.id) });
```

but this is not working , can anybody help me pls?

Comment: _"but this is not working"_ it works fine for me... Can you set a demo at http://jsfiddle.net to show me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Fgf/1/) just fine, but you can remove the `*` from the selector.

Other valid options:

```
$("div").find("[id]").each(function() { alert(this.id) });
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Fgf/3/)

Or this:

```
$("div *").filter("[id]").each(function() { alert(this.id) });
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Fgf/)

Or this:

```
$("div [id]").each(function() { alert(this.id) }); // which I think is the best
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Fgf/2/)

Comment: There are even more options, but I got tired... :)

Comment: I'd say the last one is not exactly equivalent, because an empty id attribute would lead to a different result (of course not valid...)